# Why my custom JavaFX MapView request obtain 403 error by OSM?

Tags: java, javafx, openstreetmap

I develop a custom MapView for a commercial sofware in JavaFX.
Since only one week, all my request failed with 403 code error (exemple) :

"Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://tile.openstreetmap.org/9/245/206.png"

But request success with browser like Mozilla.
I haven't change some code or configuration, just OSM black-listed me.

However, I think, I'm following the osm policy rules, like only 2 connections in same times, memory cache system, not downloading huge area with high zoom.

How can legaly acces to OSM tiles on distributed software for commercial usage ?
Usurpt Mozilla User-Agent can be a immediat solution during developpement but after ?

```
   private void loadImage(Tile tile) {
      String url = tile.getRetriever().computeURL(tile);
      if(!waiters.contains(url)) {
        waiters.add(url);
        threadPool.execute(new ComparableRunnable(url,()->{

            try {
                if(!exist(tile)) {

                    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
                    semaphore.acquire();

                    Image image = new Image(url, true);

                    image.errorProperty().addListener((obs,old,val)->{
                        if(image.isError()) {
                            Outil.loggerConsole(image.getException());
                            semaphore.release();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Outil.loggerConsole(e);
                }
            }));
```

"Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://tile.openstreetmap.org/9/245/206.png"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can legaly acces to OSM tiles on distributed software for
>   commercial usage ?

By using a third-party provider or by running your own tile server. OSM's tile servers are *not* for commercial usage. See the [Tile Usage Policy](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/). Quoting the interesting parts:

> **OpenStreetMap’s own servers are run entirely on donated resources.**
>   They have strictly limited capacity.
>
> [...]
>
> **OpenStreetMap data is free for everyone to use. Our tile servers are not.**
>
> [...]
>
> Heavy use (e.g. distributing an app that uses tiles from openstreetmap.org) is **forbidden** without prior permission from the System Administrators.

See [Alternative OpenStreetMap Tile Providers](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/#alternative-openstreetmap-tile-providers) for solutions.